# Is there a way for me to make parameters adjustable in canoe?

Tags: capl, canoe, canape, xcp

I'm trying to make parameters *adjustable* (read *calibratable*) in CANoe like what exists in CANape. In CANape, the menu item makes a parameter *adjustable* by copying it from the main memory to the pool memory. I'm trying to find a similar function in CANoe.

It would be nice if i was able to automate this and calibrate parameters during a test script.

Comment: Adjustable parameters are indeed [calibratable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calibratable) parameter in a proper automotive language. Calibration is key to developing a proper automotive software product, allowing a developmente backdoor to be used by the calibration team to finely tune some parameters in the software. Ideally, this is done before production starts. That is why, as you state in your answer, Vector Informatik develops tools ad-hoc for the task (instead of re-using CANoe or CANalyzer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating with Vector Support about this issue, They told me that CANoe does not have the capability to tune/adjust XCP parameters.
This is a CANoe Limitation and can only be done on CANape.